# JavaScript: unexpected Data error

Tags: javascript, jslint

I wrote some coding using javaScript.

```
 function showPopupSettings(userName)
        { 
           var jsonData;
           setLoading("Loading User Settings");
           jsonData = new function(){
                    this.className = "User";
                    this.methodName = "showPopupSettings";
                    this.userName = userName ;
            } 
                data = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
                $.post('ajaxpage.php',{ submit: "commonAction",data:data },
                                    function(data) {
                                        removeLoading();
                                        $("#dialog")
                                            .dialog("destroy")
                                            .html(data)
                                            .show()
                                            .dialog({
                                                modal: true,
                                                title: "User Settings",
                                                buttons: {
                                                    Cancel: function() {
                                                        $(this).dialog('close');
                                                    },

                                                    Password: function() {
                                                        showChangePasswordTable();
                                                    },

                                                    Save: function() {
                                                        saveNewUserSettings();
                                                        $(this).dialog('close');
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            });
                                    });
        }
```

By using Jslint for error free.while i was check with JsLint will show following error
line 10: Unexpected Data

how to rectify this error...

Answer (score 1):

You get that error on this line:

```
data = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
```

It's caused by the previous line, which should end with a semi-colon but doesn't:

```
jsonData = new function(){
     this.className = "User";
     this.methodName = "showPopupSettings";
     this.userName = userName ;
}; //Semi-colon here!
```

There are numerous other problems with your code. In the snippet above, you don't want the `new` keyword:

```
jsonData = function() { //No 'new'!
     this.className = "User";
     this.methodName = "showPopupSettings";
     this.userName = userName ;
};
```

On the `data = JSON.stringify(jsonData)` line you have used `data` without declaring it first, so it's leaking into the global scope. Use the `var` statement to declare `data` before you use it.

Most of the other errors I get when I run your code through JSLint are related to whitespace, so can be ignored.

Comment: also, jsonData can be declared and assigned at once

Comment: @Just_Mad - It can, but then JSLint will complain again and tell you combine the declaration with the previous one.